# Remove all entries where value is an empty Optional from map

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, option-type

I want to remove all entries where value is an empty Optional from the map. It would seem that nothing complicated, but I am trying to find a better solution that I have.

---

**Input:**

I have the following Map:

```
Map<String, Function<String, Optional<String>>> attributesToCalculate = new HashMap<>();
```

Where **key** - just a String and **value** - reference to method which returns Optional < String >

---

**Output:**

As a result, I want to get

```
Map<String, String> calculatedAttributes
```

(excluding entries where value was an empty Optional)

---

Here is my solution

```
      return attributesToCalculate.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> Pair.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().apply(someString)))
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().get()));
```

But I don't like the **.filter** part because then I have to invoke **.get()** on Optional in **collect** part.

Is there а better way (maybe without .get invocation) to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in calling get() if you have checked that there was a value before.

Comment: good question, mate :) If you've got StreamEx in the classpath, you could process values separately from keys by [`EntryStream#mapValues/filterValues`](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html). But I would proceed with @Paul Boddington's answer since it doesn't breed unneeded `Pair`s.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, Hi :) I also think so. Paul's answer completely suitable for my case. And as for StreamEx, unfortunately, we don't use it =/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As commented above, there is nothing wrong with using `get` if you have already checked that the `Optional` is not empty.

However, I think this code is best expressed without using streams.

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
attributesToCalculate.forEach((k, v) ->
    v.apply(someString).ifPresent(str -> result.put(k, str))
);
```

If you don't like using `forEach` to populate the map in that way, you can use a simple `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 4):

Using Guava, you can do this:

```
Maps.filterValues(
        Maps.transformValues(
                attributesToCalculate,
                f -> f.apply("someString").orElse(null)),
        Predicates.notNull())
```

Note that this returns a view of the underlying map, meaning any lookup or iteration will delegate to the function. If that's an issue, just copy the result to a new map.

Or you might consider [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/)'s `EntryStream`:

```
EntryStream.of(attributesToCalculate)
        .mapValues(f -> f.apply("someString"))
        .flatMapValues(StreamEx::of)
        .toMap();
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a very pretty one, and similar to for-loop:

```
 return attributesToCalculate.entrySet().stream().collect(HashMap::new, (sink, entry) -> {

    entry.getValue().apply(someString).ifPresent(v -> sink.put(entry.getKey(), v));

}, Map::putAll);
```

Comment: There is no need for statement syntax here, you can simply use `(map,entry) -> entry.getValue().apply(someString).ifPresent(v -> map.put(entry.getKey(),v))` as accumulator function. And there is no reason to provide an invalid merge function like an empty block, as a simple `(m1, m2) -> m1.putAll(m2)` or even simpler, `Map::putAll`, would do the job.

Comment: @Holger Thank you. Fixed the `combiner` part. (I'm going to leave the statement syntax though, I'd even extract the accumulator to a separate variable as it's too long IMHO, but I believe the OP expects a one-liner)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a helper method to create your Pair:

```
public static <L, R> Optional<Pair<L, R>> of2(L left, Optional<R> right) {
    return right.map(r -> Pair.of(left, r));
}
```

Although this means to use Optional as a parameter, in this case it is not that bad imo (if you inlined the method, you wouldn't have it as a parameter...).

Then you could just do:

```
attributesToCalculate.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .map(entry -> of2(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().apply(someString)))
     .flatMap(Optional::stream) // Java 9
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Pair::getValue));
```

Comment: You can simply combine the `map` and `flatMap` step to a single `.flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue() .apply(someString).map(s -> Pair.of(entry.getKey(), s)).stream())`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using a plain old `Iterator`? This doesn't look much more verbose than some of the other stream solutions.

```
final Map<String, Optional<Object>> attributesToCalculate = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Object> calculatedAttributes = new HashMap<>();

final Iterator<Entry<String, Optional<Object>>> iter = attributesToCalculate.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    final Entry<String, Optional<Object>> current = iter.next();
    if (current.getValue().isPresent()) {
        calculatedAttributes.put(current.getKey(), current.getValue().get());
    }
}
```

Or even shorter using a plain for loop:

```
for(Entry<String, Optional<Object>> current : attributesToCalculate.entrySet()) {
    if (current.getValue().isPresent()) {
        calculatedAttributes.put(current.getKey(), current.getValue().get());
    }
}
```